# fatal error while using cakephp google oauth plugin

Tags: cakephp, oauth

Fatal error: Class 'CakePlugin' not found in /var/www/cakephp/app/config/bootstrap.php on line 43

class cakeplugin is present in /var/www/cakephp/lib/Cake/Core

I am trying to use google oauth plugin for cakephp app , after following steps as given on :

https://github.com/uzyn/opauth-google/blob/master/README.md

But when I run my app I get above mentioned fatal error,

Do I need to change the links or copy the plugin file ? Or something wrong is ther ein my approach?

Comment: make sure the names are written correctly (caps and stuff)

Comment: now what caps are we talking here?

in my directory structure 'Config' (caps C) is used under OPauth/Config...

Comment: its (small c) config in /var/www/cakephp/app/config

Comment: class cakeplugin is present in /cakephp/lib/core/Cake/plugin/cakepugin.php  (like just right here the name is misspelled)

Comment: /var/www/cakephp/lib/Cake/Core/

Comment: and why have oyu put the plugin into the lib ? put it in app/plugin

Comment: i mean cakeplugin.php is in lib, my plugin is already there in app/plugin as I mentioned , I am following all steps correctly

Comment: You might want to try to redownload and reinstall your CakePHP and make sure it's at least v2.

Comment: i will try this , and let you know if it helps

Comment: I observed one thing . when I cake bake some project it gives me path in the app starting with small letters , but by default paths start with capital letters when we unzip latest stable release of cakephp, is it problem here?

Comment: its because your cake bake shell is on the old 1.3 cake version.. trying getting a new copy of cake and go to app and do Console/cake bake! This is the good shell

Comment: what is right way to install cakephp-scripts . When I use ubuntu and use apt-get install it always say welcome to v1.3.2 console .

Comment: my cake is latest stable release